# .htaccess error 404 if not index.php is in the link

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I link to a page of my website using the HTML  href attribute, if the link is like "http://localhost/demo/en-us/index.php" it works just fine BUT if the link is in the form "http://localhost/demo/en-us/" it does to the Error 404 page.

I tried adding

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

to the .htaccess file but it give a server error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/demo/404.php

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(following|followers)?$ $2.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

I'm not really familiar with .htacces but I think it should not redirect to error 404 if the page exists.

Comment: You should take a look at the apache http server's `DirectoryIndex` directive: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: Maybe try `RewriteRule ^/demo/en-us/(.*)$ /demo/en-us/index.php?$1 [L]`?

Comment: It really depends on what the server error is... check your error logs

Comment: @Stevish it gives a ridirect 302 error. I think it has some thing to do with RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]

Comment: And... by the way... it makes absolutely no sense to have to rewrite conditions _not_ followed by a rewrite rule.